# I have problems with using find_last_of

Tags: c++, algorithm

When I try to find last occurrence of "EndProject" in file, which looks like this: (this is original VS solution file, without any changes):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "ASO", "ASO\ASO.vcxproj", "{574117CD-377D-4C5A-8B6C-B0EAFF8CE158}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "asdfasdf", "asdfasdf\asdfasdf.vcxproj", "{05527F0D-4B98-4A55-B038-3C60005566CB}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Win32 = Debug|Win32
        Release|Win32 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {574117CD-377D-4C5A-8B6C-B0EAFF8CE158}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {574117CD-377D-4C5A-8B6C-B0EAFF8CE158}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {574117CD-377D-4C5A-8B6C-B0EAFF8CE158}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {574117CD-377D-4C5A-8B6C-B0EAFF8CE158}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
        {05527F0D-4B98-4A55-B038-3C60005566CB}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
        {05527F0D-4B98-4A55-B038-3C60005566CB}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
        {05527F0D-4B98-4A55-B038-3C60005566CB}.Release|Win32.ActiveCfg = Release|Win32
        {05527F0D-4B98-4A55-B038-3C60005566CB}.Release|Win32.Build.0 = Release|Win32
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

and I'm using:

```
auto end_of_project_manifest = project_file_contents.find_last_of("EndProject");//here project_file_contents is a string filed with contents of this file.
```

the result I'm getting is 1308, which is strange because this file has only 1313 chars in total. Surely there is something wrong but what?

Comment: Possibly line ending characters getting expanded somewhere to \r\n ?

Comment: Well, what you find if you print out the stuff at position 1308? Seems like there's a good deal of more debugging you could do before asking the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::string::find_last_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) will find the last occurrence of any of the characters in the search string, not the last occurrence of the entire search string: in this case if finds the `o` in `EndGlobal`.

Use [`std::string::rfind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) instead:

```
auto end_of_project_manifest = project_file_contents.rfind("EndProject");
```

Comment: #hmjd great, this works as intended. On the other hand, it is bit misleading that find_last_of accepts string and yet searches for char. Anyway, will accept of course.

Comment: @smallB That's why it is called `find_last_of` -- it may be assumed, that an input is a set of elements to find.